# ffmpeg to dvb-c. Need some advices

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transcoding, libx264, dvb

I'd like to get some advices about ffmpeg transcoding and broadcasting it to DVB-C environment.
Have a server, based on Linux with external GPUs based on Nvidia P4000. Target of this machine is getting live streams at HLS, then it transcode files to multicast UDP. After transcoding multicast TS gets to receiver (Sumavision EMR 3.0), then modulates into DVB-C with QAM-card for next transmission to fiber.

So, there is a strange trouble. In IPTV such stream have no visible troubles. Analyzing TS, saw an errors with PCR accuracy (>500 ms 'cause of pseudo-CBR) and very rare discontinuity errors, that could be based on source errors.
Then I take it to Sumavision and apply inbound parameters (just remultiplexing this stream with making loyal reference, buffer size values and CBR output values). Analyzer sees no problem, after putting in QAM-modulator customize output streams, such as  PSI/SI tables, frequency, symbol rate etc.

After I see the result at some test TVs. First one shows this channel great, with no visible troubles (no artefacts, no asynchronous sound). Second TV has a problem of video, it looks like a lost frames. Sometimes sound interrupts for a milliseconds. But there is no freezes 
'Cause of ETR 101 290 passes well, may be this model of TV decodes this service incorrect. Example of video record is [here](https://yadi.sk/mail/?hash=z%2B0vuUmkfUlzvFy2a46ZZCWeanuR1nuM3xecTB5FmZI4VX5j8Rila60bWUKLoh3Lq%2FJ6bpmRyOJonT3VoXnDag%3D%3D).

Here is the code of ffmpeg. May be, I missed some common parameters, that may get the output is better for such tuners. Can you see it's alright?

```
sudo -u nobody ffmpeg -threads 0 -v warning -re -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_device 2 -c:v h264_cuvid -deint 0 -i http://x.x.x.x/playlist.m3u8 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec h264_nvenc -gpu 2 -cbr true -sc_threshold 0 -filter:v scale_npp=960:540:interp_algo=lanczos -vprofile baseline -b:v 1000k -bufsize 1400k -maxrate 1400k -minrate 900k -force_key_frames 1 -g 50 -bf 0 -refs 1 -r 25 -strict experimental -c:a aac -b:a 64K -af aresample=44100 -ac 2 -flags -global_header -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 /path1/segment-1507744758-%06d.ts -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec h264_nvenc -gpu 2 -cbr true -sc_threshold 0 -vprofile high -b:v 8000k -bufsize 400k -maxrate 9000k -minrate 7200k -force_key_frames 1 -g 50 -bf 2 -refs 1 -r 25 -strict experimental -c:a aac -b:a 192K -af aresample=44100 -ac 2 -flags -global_header -f tee 
[f=segment:segment_format=mpegts:segment_time=10]/path2/segment-1507744758-%06d.ts|[f=mpegts:muxrate=9333k:mpegts_pmt_start_pid=0xB4A:mpegts_start_pid=0xB4B]'udp://y.y.y.y:1234?buffer_size=0&overrun_nonfatal_option=1&pkt_size=1316&ttl=15'
```